# How to show string value in flutter sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm using sqflite in flutter for mobile devices's local database.
I made a test table and I success print a table's value using 'debugprint'.

But I can not print the value in device's screen. Maybe because asynchronous? (I don't know exactly)

I want to print the value in screen.

This is my source code.

This is a scaffold's body

```
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text( getFirst().toString() ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

And this is a function. debugPrint's value is what I wanted.

```
Future<String> getFirst() async {

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _databaseHelper.db.rawQuery(
      " SELECT attr1 FROM Test_t");

  debugPrint(maps.toString());

  return maps.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the value as it's asynchronous. getFirst() - returns a future, to retrieve value you need to await for it.

There are few ways to do that:

FutureBuilder https://flutterigniter.com/build-widget-with-async-method-call/

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/async

Could also use states to do that...